Raw XML Data not stored in Spring Boot JPA H2 In-Mem Data base
In the Spring Boot JPA, I am trying to save the XML raw data using REST API POST request.
[POST] http://localhost:8080/employee
Raw XML Data
<Optional>
    <empId>107</empId>
    <firstName>Aston</firstName>
    <secondName>Martin</secondName>
</Optional>

package com.webprj.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee 
{
    @Id
    private int empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
}

@RestController
public class ControllerApp 
{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo empRepo;

    @PostMapping(path="/employee", consumes={"application/xml"})
    @ResponseBody
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee)
    {
        empRepo.save(employee);
        return employee;
    }
}

But, the XML raw data was not saved in my JPA H2 In-Mem Database.
I tried to save the XML raw data. However, the XML data was not saved.
It gives me null:
{
    "empId": 0,
    "firstName": null,
    "secondName": null
}


How to resolve this issue?

So without knowing how your Employee looks we should magically know what is wrong? Please add the Employee class. Next to that you are posting a list of employees but are accepting just 1, so not sure how you think that is going to work? Finally you are at least missing an @RequestBody annotation to even properly serialize back into an Employee.

Now, I have found the mistake which I have made.
Now, I got the xml raw data stored in the H2 Data base.
Thanks.
